# Check the length of the number entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to write in text box and check if is integer and less than 16 numbers. I have the following JavaScript codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doCheck(field) {
    if (isNaN(document.getElementById(field).value)) {
        alert('this is not a number');
        document.getElementById(field).focus();
        document.getElementById(field).select();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return doCheck('number');">
national id=<input type="text" name="nat" id="number">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the length of string inside the text box using this

```
function doCheck(field) {
     var len = document.getElementById("number").val().length;
     if(parse.Int(document.getElementById(field).value) && len < 16) {
          return true;     
     }
     else {
          alert('your alert');
          document.getElementById(field).focus();
          document.getElementById(field).select();
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(field).value.length
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNAN()` checks whether a number is an illegal number of any type, not only integer. So you have to use something else there, a regular expressions maybe.
To get the length of the field you can simply use:

```
document.getElementById(field).value.length
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure you parse it as an integer.

```
function doCheck(field) {
  var input_value = document.getElementById(field).value;
  if(isNaN(input_value) || parseInt(input_value,10) != input_value || input_value.length < 16) {
      alert('this is not a number');
      document.getElementById(field).focus();
      document.getElementById(field).select();
      return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: parsInt without an explicit base (radix) could cause strange results with some input. I suggest `parseInt(input_value, 10)`. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)